# Бесконечный список ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы список `ListView` можно было крутить бесконечно. То есть, чтобы когда элементы списка заканчивались, они снова начинались сначала.

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146239/circular-or-infinite-listview-with-arrayadapter)

Comment: Можете посмотреть пример, как это устроено [Здесь](https://github.com/guillep/PullToRefresh/tree/master/PullToRefresh)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте эти методы к адаптеру:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position % items.size());
}
```

Для получения айтема вместо

```
items.get(position);
```

используйте

```
getItem(position);
```